# Discussing [tag:memory]

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

It seems that [memory](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) is always about forgetting something. Currently there are only 2 questions about this, but I don't sense there will be any other question worthy of [memory](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) other than forgetfulness.

How should we use this tag? Or should we change it to [forget](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forget) or [forgetfulness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forgetfulness) ?

Comment: Good point. Let's go for "forgetfulness".

Answer (score 4):

While I certainly think there *could* be a use case for [memory](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory), I'm not sure that either of those two questions fit it.

Rather than "forgetfulness" I would recommend we use [forgetting](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forgetting). We want our tags to be non-judgmental, and I think that "forgetfulness" is a term that implies a repeated history of memory issues (often related to aging) while questions may be about a single failure of memory. This issue doesn't exist with [forgetting](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forgetting).

---

... that being said, I don't think that [How to remind an instructor about a message I sent them?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-to-remind-an-instructor-about-a-message-i-sent-them) is about memory or forgetting at all. Only the person the question is talking about can know if it was a lapse of memory or intentionally ignoring the OP, so the tag would be inappropriate.

Comment: With that question the memory tag was to imply that he had forgotten about the message, so I completely agree with the change

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we could create an alias? I believe these exist, so that [forgetting](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forgetting) would simply be a duplicate of [memory](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory).

Comment: You mean "tag synonyms"? In that a tag is made the parent tag, and all synonym tags when used will automatically change into the parent tag.